# Image upload to cloudinary works only on first attempt, then says "empty file" though file is full

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload a file (an image for profile picture) in my frontend (react) and send it to my backend (node/express) where I then want to send it to cloudinary for storage, and depending on if response is successful or not update DB and then redux state.
However, only some of the attempts to send to cloudinary are successful. I've logged the file on the frontend before it is sent to the backend, and it shows that there is a file there, and I log the request (req.files) in the function on the backend and it shows that the file is there, but when it is actually sent to cloudinary, it is often successful with no changes to the code, but most of the time I get `Cloudinary Error:  { message: 'Empty file', http_code: 400 }`despite all the console.logs showing a file.

in app.js on the backend:

```
app.use(
  fileupload({
    useTempFiles: true
  })
);

app.post("/editprofilepic/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  const file = req.files.image;

  if (!req.headers.id) {
    console.log("no header!!");
  }
  cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.tempFilePath, function(err, result) {
    console.log("Cloudinary Error: ", err);
    console.log("Cloudinary Result: ", result);
    if (!err) {
      console.log("RESULT PUBLIC ID: ", result.public_id);
      User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.headers.id },
        { $set: { profilePicId: result.public_id, profilePicUrl: result.url } }
      )
        .then(result => {
          console.log("RESULT FROM MONGO: ", result);
          res.status(200).send(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).send(err);
        });
    }
  });
```

the file submitting component on the frontend

```
function UploadProfilePic({ userId, setCurrentUserProfilePic, profilePicUrl }) {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

  const fileSelectedHandler = event => {
    console.log("event target, file at zero-index: ", event.target.files[0]);
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const fileUploadHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("SELECTED FILE in current state: ", selectedFile);
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("image", selectedFile, selectedFile.name);

    Axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/editprofilepic/`, fd, {
      onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
        console.log(
          "Upload progress: ",
          Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100)
        );
      },
      headers: {
        id: userId
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        const { profilePicId, profilePicUrl, _id } = res.data;
        // TODO: UPDATE USER IN REDUX
        setCurrentUserProfilePic({ profilePicId, profilePicUrl });
        console.log("SUCCESS ", res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    setSelectedFile(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className="uploadprofilepiccontainer">
      {profilePicUrl ? (
        <img src={profilePicUrl} style={{ width: "22%" }} />
      ) : null}
      <h1>edit profile pic</h1>
      <div className="uploadprofilepic">
        <input onChange={fileSelectedHandler} type="file" />
        {/* <input onChange={fireConsoleLogSelected} type="text" /> */}
        {selectedFile ? (
          <button onClick={fileUploadHandler}>upload</button>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I expect it to submit successfully every time, but a lot of the time it responds with `Cloudinary Error:  { message: 'Empty file', http_code: 400 }` and after trying many times to keep submitting, and after changing the file, it will sometimes upload a picture I tried previously instead of the one I am trying to send currently.

Comment: When I stop back end server and restart it, the first upload attempt works, but the second upload attempt fails. If I reattempt a bunch of times and change the file a bunch of times, sometimes it goes through, but it uploads one of the previous pictures I attempted to upload instead of the one currently in state in the react frontend.

Comment: also, it seems that the MongoDB User object is getting updated with different values than what comes back from the cloudinary 
 upload... different ```public_id``` and ```url``` values getting saved to the ```profilePicId``` and ```profilePicUrl``` fields on the User document in MongoDB.

Comment: one thing i can suggest is before you execute the file upload code, log the content length. This will make sure that there is at least some bytes sent to cloudinary API. Unless you have already done that.

Comment: when i log out the ```req.files.image``` before the cloudinary upload, I get ```{
  name: 'six.png',
  data: <Buffer >,
  size: 186725,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '/tmp/tmp-2-1567793584569',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  md5: 'e65bf962ceb8370936e736a63b4e4afd',
  mv: [Function: mv]
}```

Comment: but i still get ```Cloudinary Error:  { message: 'Empty file', http_code: 400 }``` even when it says the req.files.image has size

Comment: One problem was that I was using ```{return original: false}``` (used in mongodb node drive's findOneAndUpdate) instead of ```{new: true}``` (used in mongoose's findOneAndUpdate). I'm using mongoose so I should've had it set to ```{new: true}```.  Still have the problem of seeing "file empty" during upload attempts after the first

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem, also with Node and Cloudinary.  I've been trying to figure out what it is that changes when the app is reset but no luck so far.

Comment: Yeah same here too. Has anybody had success with this on Node?

Comment: I gave up and switched to using mongo db's FSgrid